# Query returns Error despite being executed succesfully (Robot Framework / JayDeBeApi)

Tags: db2, robotframework, jaydebeapi

Using the Keyword `Query` from the Robot Framework DatabaseLibrary JayDeBeApi in conjunction with DB2 like this: `${results}=  Query  CREATE TABLE SCHEMANAME.TEST_TEMP (id BIGINT, name VARCHAR(25))` is being executed (table exists afterwards).

But nevertheless RobotFramework throws a FAIL and ${results} contains the Message `DatabaseError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, SQLERRMC=SCHEMANAME.TEST_TEMP;TABLE, DRIVER=4.14.122` and often even a very simple Message `Error` after running the same statement.

**Running the query above (copy/paste) directly within a database SQL window doesn't return any error**s.

How is it possible, in RobotFramework the query is executed successfully but nevertheless an error is thrown?

Comment: Are you sure that `Query` keyword is the right one for this? I mean the documentation mentions `selectStatement` as its only argument (https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Query) and you're not passing in a select statement.

Comment: Hm, I guess you are right. 'Query' doesn't mean SQL in general, but only SELECT statements. 'Execute Sql String'  would be the correct keyword for INSERT or DROP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error SQLCODE=-601 means that you are trying to create an object that already exists. So when you say that the table exists afterwards, it means that it existed before you ran the statement. I don't know the framework you are using, but the explanation by @pavelsaman in comment seems to be a very likely cause.